# Possible to fill a table cell with a bg color?

Tags: html, colors, html-table, cell, fill

I have a table cell that isn't entirely filled with text so the bg color doesnt cover the entire cell. I still wish to have the entire table cell filled with the same color without using a background color on the whole table.

So is it possible to fill the entire cell with a color without using background color on the whole table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could assign a class to the `<td>` element and then assign a bg color using the CSS `background-color` property for that class.