# CSS Set Table Cell Background Color Using Text Inside Table Cell

Tags: html, css, colors, background, css-tables

Have basically the same problem as [Possible to fill a table cell with a bg color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041833/possible-to-fill-a-table-cell-with-a-bg-color) - text has a background color set and is in a table cell. Text background color is only behind the text, and does not fill the entire table cell, which it should.

The solution is normally to set a bgcolor on the table cell. Difference is that this occurs in many places throughout this particular website, and changing all the relevant table cells would take a very long time.

Question is, is there a way to say in CSS, either of:

1. Make the text background colour fill the whole table cell (if the text is in a table cell); or.....
2. If a table cell contains a text element which has style x, then make that table cell have a background colour (a kind of reverse inheritance)?

PS: the site was developed for IE6 originally, and IE6 already fills the entire table cell with the text's background color, so initially no issues. FF and IE 7+ work differently though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As David Dorward said, there's no way to do *exactly* what you want cleanly with CSS, however I can think of a few workarounds...

Assuming your html is something like this (i.e. the thing with the background color is the only thing in the table cell):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
        <td><span class="bg" >test</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
        <td>test with longish string<br/> over two lines<td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You could do this to your CSS:

```
td { height: 100%;}
.bg { background-color: #f00; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
```

It works in this simple example (at least in firefox 3.5), but could have other side effects depending on what the content of your html looks like.

---

**Edit**: Another option if you're ok with hacking it via javascript, is to use jQuery like this:

```
$(function() { $("td:has(span.bg)").addClass("bg"); });
```

This works on the above example html/css, but would obviously need to be changed to match your css classes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for this - can see why it should work, but no joy for our particular setup (we have anchor tags instead of spans in the table cells, don't know if that matters). Will just leave it for now as another reason to redevelop the particular app.

Answer (score 0):

No.

CSS, currently at least, has no way to style an element based on anything that appears after the start tag for that element in the document. So you cannot style an element based on it's content.

Answer (score 0):

Well If you want just an entire cell covered, this doesn't require css, unless you want to use it:

```
<table width="100" height="100" border="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td bgcolor='red'>This is Red</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor='blue'>This is Blue</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

It works in FireFox and IE8 and 7. It covers the entire cell even if the text doesn't.

Comment: From the question:  "The solution is normally to set a bgcolor on the table cell. Difference is that this occurs in many places throughout this particular website, and changing all the relevant table cells would take a very long time."

Comment: I would normally *not* want to place pure presentation such as colour in the HTML, especially as presumably all other colours are set by CSS.