# html 1 _ how to color particular table cells?

Tags: html, xhtml-1.0-strict

[this is the result i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MAtf.jpg)
[this is the result i am getting(ignore the image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihRft.png)

This is my code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Practical 4 </title>
        <meta  charset ="UTf-8">
    </head>
    <body bgcolor ="lightblue">
        <table border="1" bordercolor="black"  cellspacing="1" align ="center">
        <tr>
        <td bordercolor ="red"> ** </td>
        <td bordercolor ="blue"> আমার </td>
        <td bordercolor ="green">দেশের </td>
        <td bordercolor = "red" >**</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bordercolor ="red">**</td>
        <td bordercolor ="darkblue" colspan="2" rowspan="2"> <img src="image_to_use.jpg"></td>
        <td bordercolor ="red"> ** </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bordercolor ="red" >**</td>
        <td bordercolor ="red" >**</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td bordercolor ="red"> ** </td> 
         <td bordercolor ="blue">নাম</td>
         <td bordercolor ="green">বাংলাদেশ </td> 
         <td bordercolor ="red">**</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

## it would be very helpful if i could know how to color particular table cells

Comment: Don't use XHTML (not that, despite your tags, you are in the first place). Do use HTML. [Do use a validator](https://validator.w3.org/). Don't use semantic markup (in particular tables) for its layout side effects. [Do use CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS) for the look and feel of websites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to fill a table cell with a bg color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041833/possible-to-fill-a-table-cell-with-a-bg-color)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> Practical 4 </title>
    <meta  charset ="UTf-8">
</head>
<body bgcolor ="lightblue">
    <table border="1" border-color="black"  cellspacing="1" align ="center">
    <tr>
    <td style=" border-color :red;"> ** </td>
    <td style=" border-color :blue;"> আমার </td>
    <td style=" border-color :green;">দেশের </td>
    <td style=" border-color :red ;" >**</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style=" border-color :red;" >**</td>
    <td style=" border-color :darkblue ;" colspan="2" rowspan="2"> <img src="image_to_use.jpg"></td>
    <td style=" border-color :red;"> ** </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td style=" border-color :red ;" >**</td>
    <td style=" border-color :red ;" >**</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td style=" border-color :red;"> ** </td> 
     <td style=" border-color :blue;">নাম</td>
     <td style=" border-color :green;">বাংলাদেশ </td> 
     <td style=" border-color :red;">**</td>
     </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of HTML attributes, you should use CSS.
You can color your cells with for loop in JS.

Comment: the code has to be done using only html 1

Comment: @iosonobg — How?

Comment: @nebulae — HTML 1 doesn't exist as a published specification. [HTML 2](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1866) was the first published version of HTML and doesn't support tables or anything colour related. "Not using CSS" is a nonsense requirement and you have either misunderstood the assignment or been given a really bad one.

Answer (score -1):

You can color your table cells with access specifier. If you want to apply the same color to multiple cells use 'class'.

**

if you want to apply different color to each cell use 'id';

**

In CSS:

Style based on class

```
.classname{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Style based on id

```
.idname{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Welcome SO @zubair-noor :) It's like you're confusing `.classname` and `#idname` in your answer https://www.w3docs.com/learn-css/css-id-and-class.html

Comment: you can set any class name and unique id in your code.

Comment: yes, but you wrote `.idname{` which in fact is setting a class style. what i was pointing out is that you didn't pay attention to use hash instead of dot.